# C++ thread program doesn't terminate

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers

I have no idea why my code doesn't terminate. 
It is probably some obvious thing I miss here, please help!

```
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MyClass *m = new MyClass();
    thread t1(th,m);

    delete m;
    m=NULL;
    t1.join();
    return 0;
}

void th(MyClass *&p)
{
    while(p!=NULL)
    {
        cout << "tick" << endl;
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: It could be due to compiler optimisations assuming that `p` never changes because it can prove that it is never written to inside the `while(p!=NULL)` loop, and thereby turning this loop into an infinite loop.  Try adding the `volatile` storage class specifier to the parameter `p`: this tells the compiler that it can't assume anything about what the variable contains, so it will reread it from memory each time (at least under C++03; though I think the semantics changed in C++11).

Comment: @j_random_hacker: No, don't use `volatile`: it doesn't give the necessary synchronisation or atomicity for access from multiple threads (it might "work" by accident on some platforms whose underlying hardware provides those properties, but it isn't a portable solution). You need either `std::atomic`, or protection with a mutex.

Comment: Also, have a look at condition variables for thread communication instead of polling shared variables.

Comment: @j_random_hacker, `volatile` has **nothing** to do with multithreading in standard C++. Whoever upvoted your comment should be shot.

Comment: That code should not compile, your compiler is buggy. G++ 4.7 and later give an [error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/32a4fe70f3f56c5f)

Comment: @JonathanWakely: You must be talking about changes in C++11.  In previous versions of C++, it was common knowledge that such optimisations were performed by compilers, and that one way to force them to behave was to label the polled variable `volatile`.  This was a perfect solution for e.g. updating a progress bar in a GUI thread by reading a `volatile int` from the main thread (yes, making the *wild* assumption that a platform `int` could be read/written atomically).  But thanks for the hostility, it's much more useful than an explanation.

Comment: @j_random_hacker, it's not a perfect solution at all, it worked on Windows due to a non-standard interpretation of `volatile` but doesn't provide any synchronisation on other platforms. See http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/volatile-vs-volatile/212701484 for an explanation, the hostility is because I'm very tired of seeing bad advice about `volatile` here on SO.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: You're not *just* assuming atomicity. You're also assuming that changes made on one core are visible to threads running on other cores (with separate memory caches and such). That's the case on most (but not all) current processors; but is increasingly difficult to support as the number of cores increases. At some point, when processor vendors decide they can no longer practically support that, code wrongly relying on `volatile` will break horribly.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: That was a characteristically great article from Sutter, but I interpret it as **backing up** my claim about `volatile` being appropriate for the progress bar scenario in C++03 (before `std::atomic<T>` existed).  Did you read p. 2 of the article?  Besides atomicity, the only extra assumption needed for correctness in my scenario is that memory writes are eventually visible to reads by other threads in the same process.  I can see why many-core + caches might one day make this untenable, but for now it seems perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: And incidentally, I'm sick of the attitude that it's shameful not to know everything in a 700-page language standard, including how to "correctly interpret" ambiguous semantics (see, e.g., "one reading of the standard" in Table 1).

Comment: I'm not talking about knowing everything in the standard, just the "use volatile to fix your race conditions" myth, which is nothing to do with the standard and never has been. My attitude gets worse and worse because the people perpetuating the myth always insist it works and continue to argue their case. The text you refer to in Table 1 is in the column that is **not** related to multithreading, and p. 2 is also **not** related to multithreading (it's about operations within a given thread, not across threads). So neither makes `volatile` correct for multithreading.

Comment: Finally, I said nothing about it being shameful not to know, or even that you shouldn't have made your first comment. I criticised the person voting it up.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Your claim that Table 1 and p. 2 are "not related to multithreading" is baffling.  `volatile` semantics applies to *any and all* mechanisms by which a memory address could be externally modified; where does it say in the article (or in the C++03 standard) that stores by other threads are specifically excluded?  Of course it does not, because this is one of the *most useful and commonly encountered* means by which such a modification could take place.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Think about it: Suppose we have a single-CPU computer, and the "custom board" that writes directly to M in p. 2, para. 1 has also a single CPU on it.  What is the combined setup now *exactly like?*  Hint: It's exactly like a __-CPU computer running __ thread on each CPU.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: In short your understanding is flawed, and since you have not yet apologised for being rude while promulgating it, I feel inclined to add: it's been a while since I've seen something as contrived as the distinction you attempt to draw between my first comment and the upvote on it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The thread is being given a copy of `m`, not a reference to it. Use a reference wrapper to give it a reference:

```
thread t1(th,std::ref(m));
```

The program will *probably* end as expected then; but you still have undefined behaviour due to the data race of modifying `m` on one thread, and reading it on another without synchronisation. To fix that, either use `std::atomic<MyClass*>`, or protect both accesses with a mutex.

Comment: That's what I thought too at first, but the argument is actually *a reference to* a pointer to `MyClass`, so assignments in the main thread to `m` should be visible via `p` in the new thread.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: No, a copy of `m` is passed to the `thread` constructor, and the thread receives a reference to that copy. You need `std::ref` to get a reference to `m` itself.

Comment: I see now, thanks.  I thought that this kind of thing was no longer a problem thanks to "perfect forwarding" in C++11 -- is there a reason why the `thread` ctor can't "do the right thing" automatically here?

Comment: @j_random_hacker: "the right thing" depends on how the thread object and its arguments are used, not just on whether the function expects a reference. Sometimes you'd want to bind to a copy, for example if the argument's lifetime is going to be shorter than the thread's.

Comment: See also http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread, arguments are copied (or moved) to thread-accessible storage. Note the use of `std::decay`, which forces a copy of the pointer rather than forwarding as a reference. So, it is decided that "the right thing" is to be safe and not risk dangling references, and that you have to be explicit if you do want to pass a reference by using `std::ref`, as Mike pointed out.

Comment: I agree that in that scenario you would want the parameter to bind to a copy, but I believe it's a terrible design wart in C++ that this creation of temporaries for subsequent binding to references happens *implicitly*.  A much safer and simpler system would have been to make such cases compiler errors, and provide a way (say, "std::copy(x)") to allow the caller to explicitly request a copy.  Then reference types could be forwarded the same way as every other type.

Comment: @j_random_hacker, it's not a design wart, it's a compiler bug. The OP's code should not compile on a [conforming implementation](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/32a4fe70f3f56c5f), specifically because the argument should be forwarded so that it can't bind to a reference.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: I had a feeling that it ought not to compile, because the reference is non-const, and (at least in C++03) only const references have the power to cause temporaries to spring into existence to satisfy themselves.  But I intended my criticism to extend to the (currently legal) case of implicit-temporaries-to-satisfy-const-refs, too.

Comment: Indeed, g++ 4.8.2 and clang++ 3.4.1 both give for me: `error: no type named 'type' in 'std::result_of<void (*(MyClass *))(MyClass *&)>'` for the line `thread t1(th, m);`

Comment: @sgvd, if they both give that error then you're using libstdc++ with both compilers, so only really testing one implementation. libc++ says  `/usr/include/c++/v1/thread:333:5: error: attempt to use a deleted function` which is not very clear either.